# Using Django auth to grant temporary access to AWS S3 objects

Tags: python, django, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose I've built a web application with it's own auth system. In my case it's built in Django, but it could be Rails, Node, etc. In this application users upload files to AWS s3, and those files can be made private, e.g., only available to the user that uploaded the file. I don't want to have to create an S3 policy for each user, so in order to achieve this I would like to have my application do the authentication/authorization, and then somehow communicate to S3 that this user temporarily has permission to the S3 object.

Looking through the AWS docs I've found the following methods:

- [SAML 2.0 Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_saml.html)
- [Using Amazon Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_cognito.html)
- [Federation using a third party Identity Provider (IdP)](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313)

These articles are useful, but they all assume the the auth provider is using a standard such as OpenID or SAML 2, or that the application is using a 3rd party to do the auth (e.g., Google, Facebook).

In order to have my Django application perform the auth leg, do I need to set it up as an OpenID/SAML auth provider? Or is there a more direct way to perform this workflow?

If someone could point me to an example or the appropriate documentation it would be much appreciated.